# Angular 4: Using Custom RouteReuseStrategy causes Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: angular-ui-router

The custom Route reuse strategy is as follows,

```
import { RouteReuseStrategy,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,DetachedRouteHandler} from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy extends RouteReuseStrategy {
shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {}

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { return false; }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle { return null ; }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log("inside shouldReuseRoute...");
      return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig ;
    }

  }
```

I get this below error

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>           at __extends (http://localhost:8000/app/UMSClient/com/ipc/ums/modules/shared/CustomRouteReuse.service.js:7:73)

I read through stack overflow posts and couldn't locate a solution. Once this works I want to ensure one of my child component gets reloaded instead of Re-use and then attach component going forward in the project.

I provided in AppModule

```
{
    provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
    useClass: CustomRouteReuseStrategy
},
```

I change extends to implements and the error goes away but the custom route re-use does not work.

i am using angular 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my workspace structure. Angular 2 version was picked up by build wrongly when angular 4 was intended. When I corrected this, it started working fine.

Comment: What did you do to correct it?  That would be helpful information for future developers.

Comment: My workspace gulp was configured such that it picked up files from node_modules folder in a certain location for the build. NPM installed the angular 4 files in another location. Hence the run time was not having angular 4 files and was always failing. When the node_modules folders were made sync everything worked fine.

Comment: You should include that information in your answer, not as a comment